# Goto not working properly in batch script

Tags: batch-file

Given the following:

```
@ECHO OFF
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

cls
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.krohne.OpticheckMobile/Droid.MainActivity -e run_bb_tests true
adb logcat -c

set condition=false

goto while

:end
    echo macac
    exit 0


:while
    adb logcat -d -v raw | find "BBTests" | FOR /f "delims=" %%a in ('more') do ( 
        @echo Line is %%a 
        if %%a==BBTestsCompleted (  
            echo Condition met. Exiting now ..                  
            goto :end
        )
    )
goto :while
```

The script is not exiting through :end label, but it loops the while condition forever (the if statement is met)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command line under `:while`:

```cmd
    adb logcat -d -v raw | find "BBTests" | FOR /f "delims=" %%a in ('more') do (
```

contains [pipes (`|`)](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html), each of which initiates a new [Command Prompt (`cmd`)](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) instance for either side, so the `for /F` loop in the pipe is not executed in the hosting `cmd.exe` instance where the batch script runs in. Therefore, it cannot find the label `:end`. Furthermore, there are two contexts in which `cmd.exe` can run: Command Prompt context and batch file context; the instances created by a pipe are running in Command Prompt context where labels cannot be used as their usage is limited to batch file context and `goto` just has no effect.

For your code to work you must move the `for /F` loop into the hosting `cmd.exe` instance. This can be achieved by moving the pipes into the command line that is executed by the `for /F` loop (note that they need to be escaped like `^|` to become hidden from the hosting `cmd.exe` instance):

```cmd
    for /F "delims=" %%a in ('adb logcat -d -v raw ^| find "BBTests" ^| more') do (
```

Answer (score 0):

In the while class adb command contains pipes which mean that if one command failed execute other if that also fails execute other and that's the reason behind that you are not getting desired output, for this execute every adb command individually in :while class rather that using pipes